# Store "Tip of the Day" data in single file or each separately?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have about 100 different pieces of data for a "Tip of the Day" function for a WordPress site and the tips will be rotated through so that the user will get a new one every day and won't see a repeat for months at a time.

I am setting up the code to pull each day's tip using PHP and am wondering which way would be best.

- Creating an array of all tips then pulling the appropriate one.
- Saving each tip as a separate file that gets included on the fly.
- Use a switch/break structure of all different tips.

My instinct is that using separate files would be the least expensive to the processor but I've been wrong plenty about how much stuff costs. It feels like keeping everything in one file is a lot of unnecessary overhead to the server but creating/storing the data that way would be most convenient. I'd prefer to not have to monkey with using MySQL so that the client can easily add more items but I could do it if a db is that much more efficient.

Comment: You could always include an interface for adding tips o' the day to the DV for the admin, couldn't you?

Comment: Writing to a file, especially under user management, would ultimately become the most expensive. *Do not try this at home kids*.

Comment: Sounds like the database is the way to go. Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processor time is the least of your worries here. I doubt any of the things you mentioned would have an impact on processing time in comparison to the rest of wordpress.

I would create a table in the database and make a row for each tip.

Of the ideas you mentioned, creating an array in 1 file is best. Having a bunch of small files will quickly become a giant mess to manage.

Comment: A *row* for each tip, I assume?

Comment: And if you want to make a interface for adding new tips, storing them in the database would by far be easiest to implement.

Comment: @TheNail row, column, table, whats the difference? :P